# Mathematica derivative not matching when I take derivative by hand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to take the derivative of this with respect to eta:

```
fabc = 1/2 (-3 + 27/(2 + x)^2 + (1 - 1/(1 + (-1 + x) c[eta/cc])^2)/
   c[eta/cc] + 2 Log[x])
```

Here I take the derivative:

```
totalderivativeb = FullSimplify[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(eta\)]fabc\)]
```

The result is:

```
((-1 + x)^2 (3 + (-1 + x) c[eta/cc]) Derivative[1][c][eta/
  cc])/(2 cc (1 + (-1 + x) c[eta/cc])^3)
```

This result is different than what I get if I take the derivative by hand. Additionally, if I take the finite difference derivative of my function, it matches what I get by hand (numerically), but does not match at all what mathematica gives me.

I have pulling my hair out all day trying to figure out what I am doing incorrectly in mathematica and why it gives me a different answer.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is it not handling some chain rule or something?

Note that "cc" is just a constant.

When I take the derivative by hand, I get below. sorry it is my C++ code. I know it's messy, but it is correct, whereas the mathematica result is not correct. I think mathematica is not doing the chain rule or something appropriately.

```
  double d = 1.0+(x-1.0)*c(rpf);
  double u1 = c(rpf)* 2.0*d*(x-1.0)*cprime(rpf)/d/d/d/d  - (1.0 - 1.0/d/d)*cprime(rpf);
  double u2 = 2.0*c(rpf)*c(rpf);

  double first = u1/u2;
```

Note that "rpf" = eta/cc

Comment: `This result is different than what I get if I take the derivative by hand.`  what is your hand derivative looks like?

Comment: Just added to answer. The derivative by hand is given by "first" where you can see it defined above

Comment: Note that mathematica gives me a "cc" in the answer outside of the function, whereas taking it by hand, everything seems to cancel out.

Comment: Wow! In fact, that is the difference! My solution by hand has no 1/cc in it, but mathematica has it! Why does mathematica give this? My solution by hand is correct

Comment: If I put the mathematica solution into my code, but remove the cc in the denominator, it matches my finite difference derivative. I am so confused over why this cc is in there, if it cancels out when doing it by hand

Comment: What do you expect `D[f[x/a], x]` to return?

Comment: In your handsolution `cprime` isn't defined? `cprime=D[c[eta/cc],eta]` or `cprime=c'[eta/cc]`And that's the point where the difference occurs, I think!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I think you may be right. In mathematica c'[eta/cc] means the derivative of c with respect to eta/cc, whereas in my C++ code, c' was derivative of c with respect to just eta. I think this is why I thought mathematica was wrong. It's not wrong, it just interprets the derivative differently

Answer (score 2):

I would be *shocked* if Mathematica gave the wrong derivative. It's more or less a solved class of problems with very simple rules. If any part of the implementation was wrong, I have to imagine huge numbers of derivatives would be broken.

Your `cc` only ever appears in the denominator, so there should be no chance to cancel out. Working it out by hand, I get the same as Mathematica. I would recommend applying the derivative rules manually and asking Mathematica to evaluate the derivative of each part to see if you agree.

```
fabc = 1/2 (-3 + 27/(2 + x)^2 + (1 - 1/(1 + (-1 + x) c[eta/cc])^2)/c[eta/cc] + 2 Log[x])
f = 1 - 1/((x - 1) c[eta/cc] + 1)^2
g = (2 c[eta/cc])^-1
fp = D[f, eta]
gp = D[g, eta]
```

$1-\frac{1}{\left((x-1) c\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right)+1\right)^2}$

$\frac{1}{2 c\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right)}$

$\frac{2 (x-1) c'\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right)}{\text{cc} \left((x-1) c\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right)+1\right)^3}$

$-\frac{c'\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right)}{2 \text{cc} c\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right)^2}$

```
FullSimplify[f gp + g fp == D[fabc, eta]]
(* True *)
```

As Carl Woll pointed out, my guess is that you haven't accounted for the fact that

$\frac{\partial }{\partial \text{eta} }c\left(\frac{\text{eta} }{\text{cc}}\right) = \frac{1}{\text{cc}}c'\left(\frac{\text{eta}}{cc}\right)$